How do I make a command that makes a comma-separated list where all the items are bold?
I want a command that, when given a list of things, outputs a comma-separated list where all the items are bold and with an "and".
For example, if I do \wordlist{one,two,three}, I would want it to output "one, two, and three".

Welcome! I recommend having a look at the clist module of the interface3.pdf

A modification of ljguo's answer which uses a function built into the clist module to print the list.
That is the kernel already gives us
\clist_use:nnnn { <comma-separated input> } { <separator between a pair> } { <separator between two items if at least three in list > } { <separator between final two> }

so we don't really need to reinvent it. We basically want
\clist_use:nnnn { #1 } { ~ and ~ } { , ~ } { ~ and ~ }

except we want only the items to be bold and not the separators. Assuming 'words' are words (or phrases or sentences) and don't include paragraph breaks, we can just say
  \textbf {
    \clist_use:nnnn { #1 } {  ~ \textmd {and} ~  } { \textmd{,} ~ } { ~ \textmd{and} ~ }
  }

We couldn't use \text... macros if we had paragraph breaks, but then the punctuation would look very odd, so it seems safe to assume we don't in this particular case.

\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725341/
% addaswyd o ateb ljguo: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725340/

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\wordlist}{m}{
  \textbf {
    \clist_use:nnnn { #1 } {  ~ \textmd {and} ~  } { \textmd{,} ~ } { ~ \textmd{and} ~ }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\wordlist{one, two, three}

\end{document}


Thanks for the correction, it helped me learn more.

@ljguo it wasn't intended as a correction. your code should work fine. this just struck me as a more straightforward approach.

I forgot \textmd.

@ljguo I've ... er ... read bits of the source code implementing font selection rather recently.  mostly because I need to interfere.

\documentclass{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\wordlist}{m}{
  \int_step_inline:nn { \clist_count:n { #1 } }
    {
      \int_compare:nTF { ##1 = \clist_count:n { #1 } }
        {
          and~\textbf{ \clist_item:nn { #1 }{##1} }.
        }
        {
          \textbf{ \clist_item:nn { #1 }{##1} },~
        }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\wordlist{one, two, three}

\end{document}


Next you want italics or maybe something else. It's easy to accomplish it in a fairly general way.
First we store the items in a sequence, then we process the items feeding them as argument to the desired command and output the new sequence with separators. From the manual interface3 we see that the arguments to \seq_use:Nnnn are

the sequence to use;
the separator if there are just two items;
the general separator between items, except the last two, if there are more than two;
the separator between the last two items, if there are more than two.

If you prefer the Oxford comma, the last argument should be ,~and. Note that in the scope of \ExplSyntaxOn, ~ denotes a space (explicit spaces are ignored).
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\wordlist}{O{\textbf}m}
 {% #1 is a one-argument command, #2 is a comma separated list
  \testaccount_wordlist:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \testaccount_wordlist:nn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_in_seq {#2}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_out_seq \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_in_seq
   { #1{##1} }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_out_seq {~and~} {,~} {~and~}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\FBOX}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
  \fbox{\,\vphantom{Ay}#1\,}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\wordlist{one,two,three}

\wordlist[\textit]{one, two, three}

\wordlist[\FBOX]{one, two, three}

\wordlist{one,two}

\wordlist[\textit]{one, two}

\wordlist[\FBOX]{one, two}

\wordlist{one}

\wordlist[\textit]{one}

\wordlist[\FBOX]{one}

\end{document}


Maybe you want to use the Oxford comma in some cases, but not by default.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\wordlist}{sO{\textbf}m}
 {
  % *-version uses the Oxford comma
  % #2 is a one-argument command, default \textbf
  % #3 is a comma separated list
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}
   {% *-version, we want a comma
    \testaccount_wordlist:nnn {#2} {#3} {,}
   }
   {
    \testaccount_wordlist:nnn {#2} {#3} {}
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \testaccount_wordlist:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_in_seq {#2}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_out_seq \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_in_seq
   { #1{##1} }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__testaccount_wordlist_seq_out_seq {~and~} {,~} {#3~and~}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\FBOX}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
  \fbox{\,\vphantom{Ay}#1\,}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\wordlist*{one,two,three}

\wordlist{one,two,three}

\wordlist[\textit]{one, two, three}

\wordlist[\FBOX]{one, two, three}

\wordlist{one,two}

\wordlist[\textit]{one, two}

\wordlist[\FBOX]{one, two}

\wordlist{one}

\wordlist[\textit]{one}

\wordlist[\FBOX]{one}

\end{document}


